# SharePointOnlineCredentials Missing or not found

Tags: c#, configuration, sharepoint-online

I have added Sharepoint reference in my project. Even after adding reference, it is showing:

> SharePointOnlineCredentials Missing or not found.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Added tags relevant to the post

Comment: If it's 2022 and you're using the Microsoft.SharepointOnline.CSOM package and find `SharePointOnlineCredentials` isn't found, it's been removed. See this [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#using-modern-authentication-with-csom-for-net-standard) from the docs

Answer (score 16):

Add this package "Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Online.CSOM"

Comment: doesn't appear that this library supports aspnetcore

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same issue

It was due to the reason that I did not install the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime package in the NuGet

[image]

Make sure that both the NuGet packages are installed in the solution

Answer (score 4):

Even having SharePoint references if you are not targeting .NET Framework, the error occurs because the `SharePointOnlineCredentials` class is not present in CSOM for .NET Standard.

You can see the explanation here (as @Aaron noticed): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard#using-modern-authentication-with-csom-for-net-standard.

> Using user/password based authentication, implemented via the `SharePointOnlineCredentials` class, is a common approach for developers using CSOM for .NET Framework. In CSOM for .NET Standard this isn't possible anymore, it's up to the developer using CSOM for .NET Standard to obtain an OAuth access token and use that when making calls to SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right click on the project Click on Add Reference
2. In the Assemblies, select Extensions  Make sure that you have check both,
   `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and
   `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime`
3. Add `using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;` in your references

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you are missing a reference to another required assembly.  Check this out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx.

If that doesn't solve it, check to be sure that you are using the correct SDK/runtime versions for the Sharepoint version you are trying to deploy for.